# PHPDoc - Function exits

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

**Is there a way to document that a particular function calls `exit()`?**

The use case is that we have a function that is responsible for handling redirects (checks for already sent headers, set the response code, etc...) and then crucially calls `exit()`. Unfortunately, PHPStorm has no idea that this particular function terminates execution and thus suggests further warnings as if this function has returned when in practice, it never would.

Comment: I wrote an answer to another (different) question where I explain why I think you should exceptions rather than header/die: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23855247/951387

Comment: @jornane The idea that an exception is raised in anything other than an exceptional circumstance is pretty much an anti-pattern to me. Your argument about it allowing for clean up code to be run is just as possible with a redirect method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10673 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

ATM I may only suggest placing explicit `die()` or `exit()` calls after such function calls.

Comment: That's what I'm after. I like the idea of @noreturn.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too old but now you can describe a function or method that calls die() or exit() by using `@return never` in PHPDoc:

```php
/**
 * @return never
 */
function dead_inside(): void
{
    die();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is never passed up the call stack so you have to add `@return never` and `void` return definition to every function that call a function that calls a function ... that calls a function that calls `die()` or `exit()`

Comment: Note: you **MUST** define a `void` return type **AND** `@return never` PHPDoc or PHPStorm will show "Unreachable statement" warning below your `dead_inside()` function call